Definition of an stable abelian differential and orientation around the poles
On page 685 of Handbook of Teichmüller Theory Volume III -Athanase Papadopoulos there is the follosing definition:
Definition 2.7. An abelian differential on a stable curve $C$ is a meromorphic 1-form $\omega$ on each component of $C$ satisfying the following properties:

The only poles of $\omega$ are at the nodes of $C$,
The poles are at most simple,
The residues of the poles on two branches meeting at a node are opposite to each other.

I want to understand correctly this definition:
Let $\sigma:\tilde C \to C $, the normalization of $C$ and let $p$ and $q$ the preimages of the node, then
$$\mbox{Res}_p\tilde \omega+\mbox{Res}_q\tilde \omega=0.$$
Since in general $\mbox{Res}_p\eta=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int\limits_{\gamma}\eta$, where $\gamma$ is an oriented closed path around $p$.
For the two residues I am confusing on the orientation around $p$ and $q$. On the image below, since a node is locally $xy=0$. My question is, which image have the right orientations, (a) or (b)?

Thank you.
The same question for the second image: which image have the right orientations, (a) or (b)?


Your picture needs to be on the (smooth) normalization. There is only one orientation on the smooth complex curve and hence only the usual “counterclockwise” orientation on the boundary of a disk. Your picture of a cone in $\Bbb R^3$ is misleading. You should have disks in two transverse copies of $\Bbb C$.

Thank you very mucho for yor answer, i will put another figure with the normalization.
